# Flashing the ESP8266-12F Joy-IT from raspberry

Tags: raspbian, esp8266

It is possible to flash the [ESP8266 12-F](https://wiki.ai-thinker.com/_media/esp8266/a014ps01.pdf) with the raspberry [UART](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/uart.md) or I2C pins ? Has anyone ever done this? Thank you.

**EDIT: OK it's work, finally I just had big problems with my breaboard and my connections.
...**
[image]

Answer (score 2):

> It is possible to flash the ESP8266 12-F with the raspberry UART pins ? Has anyone ever done this?

I've used the USB ports for this with `esptool.py`.

```
esptool.py --port /dev/ttyUSB0 erase_flash
esptool.py --port /dev/ttyUSB0 write_flash -fm dio 0x00000 nodemcu.bin
```

I use "nodeMCU" style boards that have a micro USB jack (so using a normal micro USB cable).  I also thought hardware flow control, which the Pi UART [conventionally lacks](http://www.deater.net/weave/vmwprod/hardware/pi-rts/), was necessary, but looking around this is not be the case, you just have to hold CH_PD and/or some other line high.  So it should be possible.

I've found the serial interface on the ESP a bit fussy -- as in good ol' `minicom` is not reliable with it, the best thing seems to be `miniterm.py`, which is part of the `pyserial` package.

Comment: No, I use a micro USB cable directly; the nodeMCU ones are big breakouts with a jack on them.  I may have used an FTDI cable at some point, I know I've had an ESP that required it (no jack on the breakout).

Comment: Have you an idea of the minimum current for the `flash boot` mode or `uart download mode` or `SDIO/SPI wifi mode please` ? I cannot find this informations , I have read the  [datasheet](https://wiki.ai-thinker.com/_media/esp8266/a014ps01.pdf).

Comment: Pretty sure the ESP pins are all 3.3V, but some breakouts may include shifters.  And don't quote me on that ;)

Comment: Thank you for your time and this informations. Yes also think the ESP8266 have 3.3V pinout but , his supply voltage is: `Voltage 3.0V ~ 3.6VˈTypical 3.3VˈCurrent >500mA` This information makes me think that it is not really tolerant ... that's what bores me actually.

Comment: typical current usage on ESP8266 less than 200mA, not more than 500mA @Ephemeral